# Compare current date and db column dates and highlight the cell in JTable

Tags: java, date, jtable, cell, highlight

I am retrieving date from a database, comparing it with current date, and if current date is 7 days less or equals the date from the database then I want to highlight the cell in JTable in which results are displayed.

Any idea how I can achieve this? Below is my code :

```
    java.util.Date dnow = new java.util.Date();
    if (dnow.equals(rs.getString("dbdate")){ 

        table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true); //Enable single cell selection
        table.addRowSelectionInterval(1, 1); // select rows
        table.setColumnSelectionInterval(1, 1);
        cell.setBackground(Color.RED);
    }
    else{

       // same as above if code
    }
```

Comment: Search Stack Overflow before posting. These topics have been addressed many times already.

Answer (score 1):

Two things you need to fix in this code:

1. `ResultSet` shall return `Date` instead of `String`

   ```
   rs.getDate("dbdate");
   ```
2. `Date` Comparison is wrong at `dnow.equals(rs.getString("dbdate")`. Look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html